# How can I email Twilio SMS attachments via Mailgun?

Tags: php, curl, twilio, mailgun

**Background:**  I use my own web app for sending and receiving SMS messages via Twilio. I insert image attachments into the message body but want to have other attachment types (e.g., PDFs) sent to my mail account.

**Answer:**  (See below.)

---

**Note to Downvoters (who think I shouldn't be asking and answering my own question:**

Please take the time to read the [official StackOverflow policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (which I did prior to writing my post). As of this date, it reads...

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer
>   their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of
>   the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15
>   reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says
>   "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page.
>   Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.

Makes sense, right? In this case, the post provides information about two very popular services (i.e., Twilio and Mailgun). If a frustrated developer has hit the wall, why should they have to ask a question and wait for an answer rather than easily finding it? 99% of time, I find answers on StackExchange without having to post a question.

Comment: It'd be nice to see if there was a question here. What you did was just post something you have and didn't give anyone a chance to post a solution for something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While stepping through media enclosures, I look for any that are not .jpg, .gif, or .png.

```
    // Look for attachments
    $numMedia = $_REQUEST["NumMedia"];
    if ($numMedia > 0) {
        $attachments = "\n\n";

        // Step through list
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numMedia; $i++) {
            // Get the attachment's URL on Twilio
            $attachment = $_REQUEST["MediaUrl" . $i];

            // If not .jpg, .gif, or .png
            if (!preg_match('~(image/jpeg|image/gif|image/png)~', $_REQUEST["MediaContentType" . $i])) {
                // Inform user in message body
                $attachments .= "[A non-image file was sent.]\n\n";

                // Note the presence of a non-image attachment
                $nonImageAttachment = true;
            }

            // If image, add a link and image tag to the message body
            else {
                $attachments .= "<a href='" . $attachment . "' target='_blank'><img src='" . $attachment . "' target='_blank'></a>\n\n";
            }
        }

        // If there are any non-image attachments, trigger the emailAttachment function
        if ($nonImageAttachment) {
            emailAttachments();
        }
    }
```

If any non-image attachments are found, the `emailAttachments` function is triggered. The function emails all attachments (even images) so that all attachments from a single SMS are kept together.

```
function emailAttachments() {
    // Get global variables for Twilio and Mailgun
    global $twilio_source, $twilio_sid, $twilio_token;
    global $mailTo, $mailFrom, $mailgun_api_key, $mailgun_url, $mailgun_domain;

    // Step through all attachments
    $numMedia = $_REQUEST["NumMedia"];
    if ($numMedia > 0) {
        // Note the recipient's number (in case we need to notify SMS sender of a problem)
        $to = $_REQUEST["To"];

        // Use the sender's number and the time for forming a filename
        $from = $_REQUEST["From"];
        $numericFrom = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $from);
        $timestamp = round(microtime(true));

        // Format the sender's phone number for use in the Subject and Body
        $prefix = substr($from, 1, 1);
        $areaCode = substr($from, 2, 3);
        $exchange = substr($from, 5, 3);
        $line = substr($from, 8);
        $formattedFrom = "{$prefix} ({$areaCode}) {$exchange}-{$line}";

        // Include the attachment count in the Subject (plural if appropriate) 
        $description = $numMedia . " " . ($numMedia == 1 ? "attachment" : "attachments");
        $subject = "Forwarding {$description} from {$formattedFrom}.";

        // Include any SMS Body text in the email's Body
        $body = $_REQUEST["Body"];
        $message = "<p>SMS from {$formattedFrom}</p><p style='margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; font-family:monospace; color:navy;'>{$body}</p>";

        // Specify the Mailgun parameters (not including the attachments)
        $mailgunParams = array(
            "from" => $mailFrom,
            "to" => $mailTo,
            "subject" => $subject,
            "html" => $message
        );

        // Set a directory and start fetching from Twilio
        $directory = "downloads/";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numMedia; $i++) {
            // Get the content type that Twilio sent and combine it with the sender's number, the timestamp, file number, and proper extension
            $contentType = $_REQUEST["MediaContentType" . $i];
            $filename = $numericFrom . "." . $timestamp . "." . ($i + 1) . "." . substr($contentType, strrpos($contentType, "/") + 1);

            // Open a file in the download directory
            $file = fopen($directory . $filename, "w+");

            // Fetch the file content with cURL
            $ch = curl_init();
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
                CURLOPT_URL => $_REQUEST["MediaUrl" . $i],
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
                CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$twilio_sid:$twilio_token",
                CURLOPT_FILE => $file
            );
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            curl_exec($ch);

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);

            // Add the file information to the Mailgun array
            $mailgunParams["attachment[$i]"] = curl_file_create($directory . $filename);
        }  

        // Establish cURL connection to Mailgun
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:" . $mailgun_api_key);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" . $mailgun_domain . "/messages");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mailgunParams);

        // Parse the result 
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = strtolower(str_replace("\n", "", trim($response)));
        $result=  json_decode($response, true);
        $status = explode(".", $result["message"]);

        // If the message was not queued, trigger function to notify the sender and post error to log
        if ($status[0] !== "queued") {
            notifySender($from, $to);
            error_log("Message not sent because of " . print_r($status, true));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        // Step through the attachment list one more time, and delete the files from the server
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numMedia; $i++) {
            $filename = $numericFrom . "." . $timestamp . "." . ($i + 1) . "." . substr($contentType, strrpos($contentType, "/") + 1);
            unlink($directory . $filename);
        }           
    }
}
```

If Mailgun does not queue the message, notify the sender to email the attachments.

```
function notifySender($respondTo, $respondingFrom) {
    // Get parameters for sending through Twilio, as well as a callback URL
    global $twilio_sid, $twilio_token;
    global $website_URL;

    // Get the email address that you want the Sender to use for sending attachments via email instead of SMS
    global $mailToAlternative;

    // Set any parameters you want Twilio to return (e.g., origination time to monitor performance)
    $timestamp = round(microtime(true));
    $callback = $website_URL . "?originated=" . $timestamp;

    // Create Twilio array
    $params = array (
        "From" => $respondingFrom,
        "Body" => "  SERVER AUTO-REPLY:\n\nPlease re-send non-image file(s) to…\n\n{$mailToAlternative}",
        "StatusCallback" => $callback
    );

    // Send to Twilio
    $client = new Client($twilio_sid, $twilio_token);
    $message = $client->messages->create($respondTo, $params);

    // Optionally do something with the result (e.g., write to log file)
    $sid = $message->sid;
    $status = $message->status;
}
```